# Flex Determinate progressBar on events

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar

Hi guys and thanks in advance.

The question is: can I have a determinate progressBar like the one posted on Adobe Support Guide:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function initImage():void {
          image1.load('../assets/DSC00034.JPG');
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:VBox id="vbox0" 
    width="600" height="600">
    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:ProgressBar width="200" source="image1"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <s:Button id="myButton" 
        label="Show" 
        click="initImage();"/>
    <mx:Image id="image1" 
        height="500" width="600" 
        autoLoad="false" 
        visible="true"/> 
</mx:VBox>
```

with show the progress of some algo or operation instead an image loading?? Can I "attach" the progressBar to an eventListener to show the progress of java (I'm using blazeDS) operation??

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

ProgressBar has a mode where you control the progress:

- set the ProgressBar mode to "manual"
- call ProgressBar.setProgress() method to indicate the percentage of completion of your task

ProgressBar does not have a method to listen to an external event.
However you can write an adapter that listens to the external event and calls setProgress() accordingly.